# Prove that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L\ne 0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

#### Proof:

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L\quad \implies\quad \forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta_1>0: 0<|x-a|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0\quad \implies\quad \forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta_2>0: 0<|x-a|<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)|<\epsilon$$

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=M\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0 : 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-M\right|<\epsilon$$

Let $\epsilon=1$. Consider $x_0$ such that $0<|x_0-a|<\min\left\{\delta(1),\delta_1\left(\frac{|L|}{2}\right),\delta_2\left(\frac{|L|}{2(1+|M|)}\right) \right\}$.
Then we have $$0<|x_0-a|<\delta(1)$$
and $$\begin{aligned}0<|x_0-a|< \delta_1\left(\frac{|L|}{2}\right)&\implies |f(x_0)-L|<\frac{|L|}{2}\\ &\implies L-\frac{|L|}{2}<f(x_0)<L+\frac{|L|}{2} \\ &\implies |f(x_0)|>\frac{|L|}{2}  \end{aligned}$$

and $$\begin{aligned} 0<|x_0-a|<\delta_2\left(\frac{|L|}{2(1+|M|)}\right) &\implies|g(x_0)|<\frac{|L|}{2(1+|M|)}\\ &\implies |g(x_0)|<\frac{|f(x_0)}{1+|M|}\\ &\implies \left|\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}\right|-|M|>1 \\ &\implies \left|\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}-M\right|>1 \end{aligned}$$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, the limit does not exist.

---

My question is whether this proof is correct or not, and if it is, why doesn't it work when $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ as well

Comment: it doesn' work when $lim_{x\to a} f(x)=0$ becuase then you'll get a lot of equations of $|f(x_0)|<0$ which is obviously not true. For example, take: $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ when $x\to 1$

Answer (score 1):

It should be $|f(x_0)| >  \frac{|L|}{2}$. But a better proof is to show that $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| \to \infty$. This is true because given $h > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \geq |L|/2$ and $|g(x)| < h$ for $|x - a| < \delta$, so that $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| > \frac{|L|}{2h}$, which can be made larger than any $M > 0$ by taking $h < \frac{|L|}{2M}$.

Comment: You'r right about the inequality sign. It was a typo.I didn't try your approach, which is admittedly simpler, because we haven't actually covered "infinite" limits yet, so I was more interested in proving this proposition using the definion of a limit.

Comment: Also, could you shed more light on why my proof doesn't work for $lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$?

Comment: @VulgarMechanick Because you use $|L| > 0$ when picking the $\delta$ for $g$